# Is there a built-in way to get a language+country locale pair?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

`global $language` only holds the language code. I wonder if there's any possibility to get a country code as well, at least of that country I set as default country at `/admin/config/regional/settings`.

Some external services need that locale (`en_US`, `cs_CZ`, `de_AT`) to be loaded in a matching language. Especially in multisites a language+country locale pair would be very handy for loading such services from within one module.

Possible workaround would be to set a new global variable holding a proper locale right?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SameerNaik - Yep, I took some ready-made PHP array from GitHub and offered this as select option on an admin settings page. Value stored in the variable table to be later used dynamically. I took an array similar to this one here: https://github.com/zenzora/php-locale-array/blob/master/locale-array.php

Answer (score 2):

you can get default country value using

```
<?php 
print variable_get('site_default_country', '');
?>
```